# Android NDK JNI undefined reference to C++ source methods

Tags: android, c++, module, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am starting to learn about the Android NDK. I haven't learned much about C/C++ coding and would like to start. I imported the simple HelloJni sample and have been messing around with this to learn as well as the docs. I am stuck and feel it may be how I am using the Android.mk. Looks like it is right but the build is not working on the second module I am testing. Here is what I have in the

```
      <project folder>/jni/
                          HelloJni.cpp
                          Android.mk
                          Application.mk
                          mytools/
                                  simplemath.h
                                  simplemath.cpp
```

I would like to use my java to call a method in HelloJni.cpp which in turn calls a method in simplemath.cpp and return a value. Simple test to just carry over number added from simplemath.

Below is all my source for each

---------------------Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloJni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJni.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

TOOLS_DIR       := $(LOCAL_PATH)/mytools
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  := $(TOOLS_DIR)
LOCAL_MODULE    := simplemath
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TOOLS_DIR)/simplemath.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---------------------HelloJni.cpp

```
#include <stl/_istream.h>
#include <stl/_string.h>
#include <stl/_string_fwd.h>

#define DEBUG_TAG "JNI Native Code..."

using namespace std;

extern "C" {

 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring str){

     simplemath mathTools;
     mathTools.add(4, 5);
     .....
     return env->NewStringUTF(str);
}
};
```

---------------------simplemath.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#define SIMPLEMATH_H

namespace std {

class simplemath{

public:
    simplemath();
    int add(int, int);
    ~simplemath();

};

}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

-----------------simplemath.cpp

```
    #include <simplemath.h>

namespace std {

simplemath::simplemath(){
}

int simplemath::add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

simplemath::~simplemath(){
}

}
```

When I do a clean on the project, I get no errors. After a build, I get the following:

```
"Compile++ thumb : HelloJni <= HelloJni.cpp

 Prebuilt       : libstlport_static.a <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi/

SharedLibrary  : libHelloJni.so

C:/Users/Geek/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/HelloJni/HelloJni.o: in function Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI:jni/HelloJni.cpp:88: error: undefined reference to 'std::simplemath::simplemath()'

C:/Users/Geek/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/HelloJni/HelloJni.o: in function Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI:jni/HelloJni.cpp:89: error: undefined reference to 'std::simplemath::add(int, int)'

C:/Users/Geek/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/HelloJni/HelloJni.o: in function Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI:jni/HelloJni.cpp:92: error: undefined reference to 'std::simplemath::~simplemath()'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libHelloJni.so] Error 1
```

Comment: `std::simplemath::simplemath` <-- It's Undefined Behavior to extend the `std` namespace, except for a few exceptions (like adding a specialization of an STL template).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't declared any dependency between your modules, use `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` to do it:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TOOLS_DIR       := $(LOCAL_PATH)/mytools

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  := $(TOOLS_DIR)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES  := $(TOOLS_DIR)
LOCAL_MODULE    := simplemath
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TOOLS_DIR)/simplemath.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloJni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJni.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := simplemath
LOCAL_LDLIBS :=  -llog 
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: That definitely led me in the right direction. This still shows me an error but the error that it showed me help me figure out what the underlining problem was. It had to do with my PATH value. I thought the path from this file was suppose to be relative to where this Android.mk is located but the error showed a path value of.......        jni/jni/mytools      so I just edited the tool path to         TOOLS_DIR       := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../mytools      THANK YOU SO MUCH